# Apache2 vHost Problem: subdomain isn't working right

Tags: apache-httpd, vhost

First: I am pretty new to Linux/Apache

My problem: I am trying to acces my forum via the subdomain forum.lumix-transporte.de. Usually you can acess it with lumix-transporte.de/forum.

My forum.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName forum.lumix-transporte.de
        ServerAdmin admin@lumix-transporte.de

        DocumentRoot /var/www/forum

        <Directory /var/www/forum>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I am trying to access the forum with forum.lumix-transporte.de I am being redirected lumix-transporte.de so to the default Apache2 page "It works!". Also the Icon of the Software is shown in the Tab.

default file in /etc/apache2/sites-available:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After executing the 2 commands that were suggested by jacek.ciach 3:

```
root@lumix-transporte:/etc/apache2# grep -R Redirect *
root@lumix-transporte:/etc/apache2# grep -R lumix-transporte.de *
sites-available/default:        ServerName lumix-transporte.de
sites-available/forum.conf:     ServerName forum.lumix-transporte.de
sites-available/forum.conf:     ServerAdmin admin@lumix-transporte.de
sites-enabled/forum.conf:       ServerName forum.lumix-transporte.de
sites-enabled/forum.conf:       ServerAdmin admin@lumix-transporte.de
sites-enabled/000-default:      ServerName lumix-transporte.de
```

//After changing via phpmyadmin in the database wcf, the table wcf1_application and changing the domainpath from /forum to / and the domainname from lumix-transporte.de to forum.lumix-transporte.de it is finally working. Thank you jacek.ciach for saying that it may be caused by the forum itself. I found that after googling some more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1st solution**

<s>Check also the order in which your `*.conf` files are processed.</s>

If a `.conf` for `*.lumix-transporte.de` is ,,run'' before `forum.conf` and has a sort of redirection directive, then the `forum.conf` will never be even processed.

So you can change the order (for example by changing the name of `forum.conf` to `000-forum.conf`) or, what is better in my opinion, modify `.conf` for `*.lumix-transporte.de` in such a way, that it won't conflict with `forum.conf` (look at `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` for wildcards and check directives which may cause a redirect).

**2nd solution**

<s>In `default` there's no `ServerName`, so when Apache processes `default` before `forum.conf`, then it sends to a client the website under `/var/www`.</s>

Add `ServerName lumix-transporte.de` (in `<VirtualHost>`) to `default` and restart Apache.

**3rd solution**

It seems, that the forum itself causes the redirection. (Check response header of `http://forum.lumix-transporte.de/` with i.e. `http://web-sniffer.net/` and you'll see...).

Comment: I dont have a conf for lumix-transporte.de . I only have an A-Record for lumix-transporte.de so *.lumix-transporte.de. But the weird thing is that I tried that with phpmyadmin already and it worked properly.

Comment: Could you explain what have you tried with phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Even there's not a `.conf` for `*.lumix-transporte.de`, your Apache has something that can be called ,,global'' or ,,main'' config file.

Comment: Where is this located? (As I said already I am pretty new) Is it the apache2.conf?

Comment: I just tried if the vHost would work at all

Comment: Where it is... it depends on your distro and the way you installed Apache. For example, if `forum.conf` is in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`, then the ,,main config'' will be in `/etc/apache2/` or in its subdirectories (try looking for every `*.conf`)

Comment: I have a default file in /etc/apache2/sites-available

Comment: Are there any other files in `sites-available`? Could you edit your post and paste the content of `default`?

Comment: Yes here is a default-ssl file. // I edited the main post.

Comment: Did what you said, nothing changed.

Comment: Check other files for redirect directives (`apache2.conf`, `conf.d/*`, ...).

Comment: Have checked everything, found nothing that could cause the redirect.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, there is something causing the redirection. If there wasn't, a client wouldn't be redirected. ;) It is very difficult to figure out what this something is, when I'm unable to see your entire configuration. Tried `grep -R Redirect *` from `/etc/apache2`? When Apache does a redirect, it has to know the destination. And the destination is in a certain file. So try also `grep -R  lumix-transporte.de *`.

Comment: ....or maybe the forum itself causes the redirect.....

Comment: I executed the 2 commands. Looks like there isnt a redirect caused by apache... (i posted it in the main post)#

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `DirectoryIndex` directive of Apache. Your forum probably does using something different than the default `index.html`.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html for more information.

Comment: Yes. It isn't index.html, it is index.php. Now my forum.conf looks like that:


`<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName forum.lumix-transporte.de
        ServerAdmin admin@lumix-transporte.de

        DocumentRoot /var/www/forum

        <Directory /var/www/forum>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.php
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>`

The problem is still there.

Comment: And you know you have `php` installed and restarted Apache after the configuration changes?

Comment: Sure i have installed php. I have reloaded apache after changing the .conf file. // Restarted apache now too, the problem still exists.